# Python urlparse urljoin

Tags: python

```
link = "http://www.test.com.tw/t/time.html"
date ="20150113"
```

I use `mergelink =  link + '/' + date` to get the result I want

ans I want to ask is there anyway to join `link` and `date` to   `http://www.test.com.tw/t/time.html/20150113`  ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Edit: I misunderstood OP's requirements before, here is the working solution, albeit very ugly in my opinion but it works:

Use **urlparse** with **urljoin**, with **rsplit**:

```
import urlparse

link = "http://www.test.com.tw/t/time.html"
date ="20150113"
url = urlparse.urlparse(link)

urlparse.urljoin(url.geturl(), '/'.join(link.rsplit('/', 1)+[date]))
```

Results:

```
'http://www.test.com.tw/t/time.html/20150113'
```

It wasn't fancy looking and indeed most of the time it will be easier to just do what @PadraicCunningham answered, way easier.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, indeed I wasn't paying attention, I thought it was just another easy url joining situation, answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

`str.format` is an easier  way to add to the url:

```
date ="20150113"
link = "http://www.test.com.tw/t/time.html/{}".format(date)
```